# University Computer Science: Parsing out integer values into a list from a string

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a problem that goes through any string and parses out specific numbers into a new list based on some given rules.

Example String:

```
'800!)176^b006$(46$*#63Z*16$*06$z5^'
```

Expected Output:

```
[ 800, 600, 64, 63, 61, 60]
```

The rules given to parse out the numbers are:

1. The numbers are non-negative integers, like 123
2. The first char of each number is always a digit.
3. If a `$` char appears immediately after a number, its digits are backwards. So `211$` is the number 112.
4. If a `^` char appears immediately after a number, it's as if that number is not present in the data, and it is omitted from the output. So for example `176^` would be omitted.
5. The numbers are separated from each other by random chars which are not `^` or `$` or digits.

I've begun the problem and get some test cases to work.

I have 3 core problems rn in my code:

*Regarding Rule 3:* My code recognizes the `$` in the string and will run through it backward and it will give me success for my test case. BUT, only if the string has nothing past `$`. I am unsure how to get it to execute for only the string before it and then move on.

*Regarding Rule 4:* I am just unsure how to omit the whole string section before the `^`

The last one is getting the code to do these operations based on the rules and then appending them to a list properly. Meaning I don't know how to get it to execute everything as a series of a substring within the given string.

```
def parse_line(s):
    """
    Given a string s, parse the ints out of it and
    return them as a list of int values.
    >>> parse_line('12$35$')
    [21, 53]
    """
    search = 0
    lst_num = []

    if len(s) > 1:
        while True:
            start = search

            while start < len(s) and not s[start].isdigit():
                start += 1
            if start >= len(s):
                break

            end = start + 1
            while end < len(s) and s[end].isdigit():
                end += 1

            if end < len(s) and not s[end].isdigit():
                if s[end] == '$':
                    rev_case = reverse(s)
                    lst_num.append(rev_case)
                if s[end] == '^':
                    continue
                end += 1

            search = end + 1
        return lst_num
    lst_num.append(int(s))
    return lst_num
```

I expect the code to return a list of the numbers only in reverse order:

```
parse_line('12$35$')
[21, 53]
```

I get a failed message error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '53$21'
```

Comment: I think focusing on the complicated cases for `$` and `^` has distracted you from the basics. Your current code won't do anything useful for the input `1X2X3`. Get that right, then figure out how to modify it to deal with `$` or `^` in place of the `X`s. You probably want to be slicing from your string: `s[start:end]` or similar.

Comment: Is it allowed to use regular expressions?

Comment: Hi there @Blckknght What do you mean by the basics? Also, when you mention slicing, how would that apply to me wanting to parse out the specific section based off the rules given.

Comment: @MiniMax We haven't learned regular expressions, so I would say that it isn't allowed.

Comment: By the basics, I mean, can your code parse numbers that don't have a special character after them? Look at my example string. Can you parse the `1`, `2` and `3`? Slicing is one way to get a substring from a main string given indecies of the start and end of the piece you want. I'm assuming that's what you were tracking `start` and `end` for, but if you don't know what slicing is, maybe you had some other plan that I don't know about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through your string, one element at a time. If the character is a digit, you can save it to a temporary list. Once you hit a non-number, you can check it for the special characters (per your rules). If the character is a `$` and you have a number in your temporary list, reverse the number and then save it to your results. If the character is a `^`, then reset your temporary list. If the character is anything else and you have a number in your temporary list, add that number to your results.

The important thing is you handle characters *one at a time* instead of potentially moving back and fourth through your string.

```py
def parse_lines(s):
    result = [] # Will be returned
    cur_num = "" # A string of the characters from the current number
    for char in s:
        if char.isdigit():
            cur_num += char
        elif char == "$" and cur_num:
            result.append(int(cur_num[::-1])) # Then reverse it
            cur_num = "" # and reset cur_num
        elif char == "^": # no need to check cur_num.. we reset it anyway.
            cur_num = "" # Then reset cur_num
        elif not char.isdigit() and cur_num:
            result.append(int(cur_num))
            cur_num = ""
    if cur_num: # Handles if a number is at the end of the input string
        result.append(int(cur_num))
    return result

test_cases = ["800!)176^b006$(46$*#63Z*16$*06$z5^", "12$35$", "", "$", "^", "5"]
for test in test_cases:
    print(f"{test}: {parse_lines(test)}")
```

**Output:**

```
800!)176^b006$(46$*#63Z*16$*06$z5^: [800, 600, 64, 63, 61, 60]
12$35$: [21, 53]
: []
$: []
^: []
5: [5]
```

Note: In the real world, I would prefer to use `regex` as [splash58's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58650941/3308951) implements very well, but your comment indicates this is for an assignment and that `regex` is *probably* not allowed.

Comment: What does the ' " ".join(cur_num) ' signify?

Comment: Sorry, originally I had `cur_num` as a list, so the call to `join` was to stringify it. It does nothing and can be removed. (edited it out)

Answer (score 1):

Find sequences of digits with optional sign $ or ^. Then for each found pair test an "option" and fill the output

```
import re
string = '800!)176^b006$(46$*#63Z*16$*06$z5^'
lst = re.findall(r'(\d+)([\$\^])?',string)

res = []
for x in lst:
  if x[1]=='$':
     res.append(x[0][::-1])
  elif x[1]== '':
     res.append(x[0])
print(res) # ['800', '600', '64', '63', '61', '60']
```